# Does electricity linger in small electronics?

Tags: digital-logic, semiconductors, binary

[image]

I'm designing a very tiny 8 bit CPU as a concept first in CircuitVerse. I designed components to eventually design this 4 bit 0-15 binary counter. Only thing I found weird is when the ALU is enabled, it adds together 0000 + 1000 (in the picture it shows 0111, I was testing something and could not reupload my screenshot) on the output pins. I feed my signal back into my PIPO register, then the clock inverts causing the ALU to disable and the PIPO to enable recording. Only thing is, it works for some reason. I expected it to no work because since the ALU is disabled. There should be no data left for the PIPO to record. How come this still works? The PIPO register I designed records every time on a clocks rising edge event.

(NOTE: I have reset enabled on my PIPO register, I did that to stop counting temporarily.)

Another thing is that my PIPO register gets all data as a snapshot I guess you could call it, so only data is recorded exactly when the clock pulse is actually transitioning. After that, even if the clock is HIGH, and you change the input, the records won't change until another oscillation of the clock. Could this be why it's working?

Comment: What do you mean by "electricity lingering?" I am not connecting the title to the question body at all.

Comment: Like does the electricity linger at the inputs of the PIPO register for a bit, linger there enough for it to exist and be recorded

Comment: You mean like gate capacitance?

Comment: I guess, I dont know if that can cause an effect on my circuit with a very slow clock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your circuit simulation, two things are happening almost simultaneously (within a small window of time):

1. The enable signal of your ALU is de-asserted, causing its outputs to become invalid (I assume)
2. There is a rising clock edge at your shift register, which causes its input data to be captured.

If, in the simulation, (2) occurs slightly before (1), then the correct ALU outputs will be captured. Obviously if (1) comes before (2), the ALU will be reset before its outputs can be captured.

Actually, in a real chip, (1) must occur after (2)+dT due to the hold time of the shift register's input DFF. (Read more here: https://www.edn.com/understanding-the-basics-of-setup-and-hold-time/)

So which one really does come first? It depends on the propagation delay of signals through your ALU, and how your simulator models it. Intuitively it feels like (2) ought to come before (1) due to the delay through the ALU, but verifying that for a real chip is not trivial.

In general I would avoid setting up this kind of [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).